# Adding distance to query results

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I tried to display distance for my search results

the code and query

```
$query = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) AS distance FROM listings HAVING distance < ' . $distance . ' ORDER BY distance') );
        foreach($query as $q)
        {
            array_push($ids, $q->id);

        }
        $placeholders = implode(',',array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
        $listings = Listing::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderByRaw("field(id,{$placeholders})", $ids)->paginate(10);
```

$query contain distance.

How do I add distance to the listings result?

Answer (score 0):

Attach the distance selection query also to the eloquent query.

Use the following approach;

```
Listing::select([
   "*",
   "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) AS distance"
])......
```

Also, why don't you use the results from the first query, you do not need to execute twice the same query.

Comment: $listings = Listing::select([
      "*",
      "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) AS distance"
   ])->having('distance', '<', $distance)->orderBy('distance')->get();

I get errors

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* from `listings` having `distance` < ? order by `distance` asc' at line 1 (SQL: select *, `(` as * from `listings` having `distance` < 5 order by `distance` asc)

Comment: Specify the table name with the asterisk "listings.*"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get result for any specific distance:

```
$radius = 15;
Listing::select(
        DB::raw("*, (6371 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians('".$lon."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS **distance**"
            )
        )
        ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
        ->orderBy("distance")
        ->get();
```